# Solving this equation that involves Lambert W function is challenging

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I'm trying to find the solution for $x$ from the following equation, which I believe involves some sort of of Lambert $W$ function or product logarithm.

$$\frac{a}{x}\left[\frac{c}{a(b-1)} + \frac{e}{(b-1)d} \right]=\ln{\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)}$$

under the following the parameter ranges: $0<c<x<a,\quad b>\frac{d+e}{d}, \quad d>0, \quad e>0 $.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Solve
$$
\frac{a}{x}\;B = \log\frac{a}{x}
$$
Try to get it in the form $v=ue^u$.  Then we can
switch it to $W(v) = u$.
$$
\frac{a}{x}\;B = \log\frac{a}{x}
\\
e^{Ba/x} = \frac{a}{x}
\\
1 = \frac{a}{x}e^{-Ba/x}\;
\\
-B = \frac{-Ba}{x}e^{-Ba/x}\;
\\
W(-B) = -\frac{Ba}{x}
\\
x = \frac{-Ba}{W(-B)}
$$

Comment: Thanks! May I ask a followup question: If the solution for $x$ can be compared with $c$? (Actually, this is my ultimate goal).

Comment: May I ask for your help once more? I posted a followup question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728905/analytical-approximation-of-lambert-w-function